# SQL Server 2008 R2: 'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to 2 databases `DB1` and `DB2`.

I have a view called `View1` which is stored in the database `DB2`. Now I want to `ALTER VIEW` from `DB1` database.

My attempt:

```
ALTER VIEW DB2..View1 
AS 
   SELECT * FROM DB2..Test;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> 'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name

Comment: If the view is in `DB2`, you need to be in `DB2` to alter it.

Comment: @marc_s, So its not possible from `DB1`?

Comment: The error message seems to tell you that this is not possible....

Comment: Are you working in `DB2`?

Comment: As pointed out already, the error message is very clear you can't do this. Why do you need to alter a view when in the context of a different database? Just change the context of your current connection and alter the view.

Comment: @SeanLange, Thank you so much.

Comment: @marc_s, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is really simple: you need to change the database

```
USE DB2
GO

ALTER VIEW View1
    ...
```

Comment: Yup! Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: What would be the recommended way of doing this if the database is parametrized?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I'm trying to run a script to create/alter a view in different database, so I'm using `EXEC (...)` to create my views.. 
But I hit a bit of a paradox:
`EXEC ('CREATE VIEW...')` will not let you specify the database.  You have to switch to that database to create the view.
But you can't do `EXEC ('USE [db]; CREATE VIEW...')` as `CREATE VIEW` will demand it be the first command.
I got around this problem feeling like I went *Inception*:
        `EXEC('USE [db]; EXEC('CREATE VIEW'))`

Comment: You are a genius! I was looking for a solution for this problem for far longer than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are self explanatory. You need to be working in the DataBase your view is for/from. Switch your connection to `DB2` and you should be able to `CREATE` and `ALTER` a/your view. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to the same database `server:DB1` in Azure Data Studio where I wanted the view, and getting the error from this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW DB1.dbo.my_View AS
SELECT ...
```

I removed the prefix and this worked:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW my_View AS
SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric's genius answer above saved my bacon.  One thing to note is that the second encapsulated EXEC will need two single quotes to open/close it, ala:  EXEC(''...'').

Also, in my case, I was creating a stored procedure, and I consequently needed to QUADRUPLE the single quotes in the stored procedure to make things work.  So,

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(25) = ''
```

became

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(25) = ''''''''
```

Fortunately, search and replace made this easy.

Comment: instead of all this, you can use `declare @sp nvarchar(776) = 'yourdb.sys.sp_executesql' exec @sp N'create view yourview as ...'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35029188)